# Использование 2 камер android одновременно

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, возможно ли использование фронтальной и задней камера телефона одновременно, и последующий одновременный вывод их в 2 SurfaceViee. Если да то как и начиная с какой версии? Пробовал писать 2 класса (1 класс вывод в Surface фронтальной камеры, 2 класс вывод во 2 Surfsce задней) и вызывать классы ро очереди, результат - Fail connect to camera service, потом прочитал где-то что нельзя в 1 приложении использовать больше 1 объекта камеры, переписал все это с 1 объектом + перед открытием другого типа камеры прописал .relese();, результат - тоже самое.

Comment: В камере LG есть функция съемки на обе камеры и фото и видео с одновременным выводом обоих изображений на экран, называется "Двойная запись", так что это возможно в принципе, но как - не подскажу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Во многих случаях](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215230/using-both-cameras-on-android-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service) это не поддерживается **самим устройством**. Наверняка ваш случай. То есть, камер две, но активной может быть максимум одна. Надёжных хаков вокруг этого найдено не было.

- *Samsung Galaxy S4* поддерживает это в [закрытом API](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/a/201/247737), недоступном широкому кругу разработчиков.
- Штатный способ работает не на всех устройствах. [Этим приложением](https://bitbucket.org/jens_grubert/androiddualcameracapture/) можно выяснить, поддерживаются ли две камеры штатно, и никакого заумного кода там нет — просто создаются две камеры с номерами `0` и `1` и вешаются каждая на свою превьюшку.

Что касается:

> нельзя в 1 приложении использовать больше 1 объекта камеры

**Не верьте.** Вот что думает [документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)):

> Your application should only have one `Camera` object active at a time **for a particular hardware camera**.

Перевожу:

> Ваше приложение должно держать не больше одного объекта `Camera` активным в любой момент времени **на каждую отдельную аппаратную камеру**.

К сожалению, насколько это возможно реально, зависит не только от количества камер, но и от возможностей чипсета (dual ISP) по приёму сигнала от двух сразу.

- [В таблице видно](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon), что у Qualcomm это есть у Snapdragon 800 и новее.
- У Samsung Exynos [придётся покопаться](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungsemiconductor/pdfs/Samsung_Exynos_Final_HR.pdf).

Благодарить за материал надо автора [вот этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188711/2076787).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать два потока. Каждый из потоков должен работать с одной камерой и с одним SurfaceView.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Пробовал через LOOPER и AsyncTask - ошибка все также Fail to connect to camera service